# Is the determinant of a RREF matrix equal to the determinant of the original matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant, gaussian-elimination

Prove or disprove: If $R$ is the [reduced row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) (RREF) of $A$, then $\det A = \det R$, where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: Show that the $\det$ of the EROs all have determinant 1.

Comment: Either I'm missing something or this is not true. If $A$ is an invertible square matrix, its r.r.e.f. $R$ is $I$, which has determinant $1$, but such $A$ need not have determinant $1$. On the other hand, each of the row reduction operations modifies the determinant of a matrix in a simple way, so one can easily compute the determinant by tracing these modifications through.

Comment: @copper, isn't multiplying a row by 17 an ERO?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Well, $17 \approx 1$...

Comment: EROs (hmm?) come in three varieties: (i) Row switching ($\det E= -1$), (ii) Row multiplication ($\det E = \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the row multiplier). (iii) Row addition ($\det E = 1$).

Comment: It is straightforward to see that either $\det R = 0$ or $\det R = 1$. Hence it is straightforward to show that, in general, $\det R \neq \det A$. Take the $1 \times 1$ matrix $A=2$, for example. The reduced row echelon form of $A$ is $1$.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I'm not sure about "proving" this, but a contradiction to your statement:

- If $A = \begin{bmatrix}
  17 & 0 \\
  0 & 17 
  \end{bmatrix}$, then $\det(A)$ = $17^2$
- If $B = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix}$, then $\det(A)$ = $1^2$  = 1

Also, $B$ is the reduced echelon form of $A$. Therefore, the determinant of a matrix and its reduced echelon form is not necessarily the same.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't simply apply directly the properties that you use with matrices, as @zthomas.nc proved it wrong:

> If A = $\begin{bmatrix}
> 17 & 0 \\
> 0 & 17 
> \end{bmatrix}$, then $det(A)$ = $17^2$

> If B = $\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 
> \end{bmatrix}$, then $det(A)$ = $1^2$  = 1.

You can use determinants properties to get sort of "echelon-determinant".

#### 1. Linearity of determinant

Given a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ we indicate its columns as $C_1, C_2, C_3, \dots, C_n$ or its rows as $R_1, R_2, R_3, \dots, R_n$.

Linearity says, for both columns and rows:

- $\textrm{det}(C_1, C_2, \dots, \lambda C_i, \dots, C_n) = \lambda\textrm{det}(C_1, C_2, \dots, C_i, \dots, C_n)$ (homogeneity);
- $\textrm{det}(C_1, C_2, \dots, C_i + \tilde C_i, \dots, C_n) = \textrm{det}(C_1, C_2, \dots, C_i, \dots, C_n) + \textrm{det}(C_1, C_2, \dots, \tilde C_i, \dots, C_n)$ (additivity).

**Note**: A consequence of the homogeneity property is

\begin{equation*}
\textrm{det}(\lambda A) = \lambda^n\textrm{det}(A).
\end{equation*}

**Note**: If two columns or rows are proportional the determinant is zero

\begin{equation*}
\textrm{det}(C_1, C_2, \dots, C_i, \dots, \lambda C_i, \dots, C_n) = \lambda\textrm{det}(C_1, C_2, \dots, C_i, \dots, C_i, \dots, C_n) = 0
\end{equation*}

#### 2. Linear combination of rows or columns

The determinant of $A$ doesn't change if we sum to a column or row a linear combination of other columns or rows

\begin{equation*}
\textrm{det}(C_1, C_2, \dots, C_i, \dots, C_j \dots, C_n) = \textrm{det}(C_1, C_2, \dots, C_i + \lambda C_j, \dots, C_j, \dots, C_n) = \textrm{det}(C_1, C_2, \dots, C_i, \dots, C_j, \dots, C_n) + \textrm{det}(C_1, C_2, \dots, \lambda C_j, \dots, C_j, \dots, C_n) = \textrm{det}(C_1, C_2, \dots, C_i, \dots, C_j, \dots, C_n) + 0.
\end{equation*}

#### 3. Echelon form

Given this two properties we can now find a sort of echelon form, in the sense that we can sum linear combination of rows and columns and use the linearity to have a simplified form of the determinant.

So the previous example A = $\begin{bmatrix}
17 & 0 \\
0 & 17 
\end{bmatrix}$ would be

\begin{equation*}
\left\lvert \begin{matrix}
17 & 0 \\
0 & 17 \\
\end{matrix} \right\rvert = 17^2 \left\lvert \begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix} \right\rvert = 17^2 = 289.
\end{equation*}