# Why the determinant of A and Row Echelon Form of A is different?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

The matrix is
\begin{pmatrix}0&-2&-3\\ \:\:\:-1&1&-1\\ \:\:\:2&2&5\end{pmatrix}
It's determinant is 6

Reduce to Row Echelon Form:
\begin{pmatrix}2&2&5\\ \:\:0&2&\frac{3}{2}\\ \:\:0&0&-\frac{3}{2}\end{pmatrix}
The determinant is -6

Why? And the interesting point is why one is 6 and other is -6? Is there any correspondence?

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203812/is-the-determinant-of-a-row-reduced-matrix-equal-to-the-determinant-of-the-origi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you reduce to row echelon form, you sometimes switch rows which multiplies the determinant by $-1$. If you do it odd number of times, as in your example,  you get the $-$ sign in front of the det.